# image uploading in new created website in magento

Tags: php, magento

i have created a new website in magento name sunilrawat(folder).now when i am trying to upload any image for any product description the image uploaded defaultly in the media folder in magento `root.uploaded` image by me unable to search that path... it show the `path.localhost//magento/sunilrawat/media//.thumbs/a.jpg` but the actual image get uploaded in the path  `localhost//magento/media/.thumbs...` please any body provide me solution what should i do to work its for my new website..

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens because Magento refers to 'downloader/pearlib/pear.ini' for paths to file locations for extensions and media.

First, take a backup of your files and database. This is always good practice with Magento as it is a delicate piece of software.

Next, check your base URLs in your database under the core_config_data table. Make sure they DO have the trailing slash:

```
www.mystore.com - bad

www.mystore.com/ - good
```

Of course, they SHOULD have the `http://` or `https://` before them, stackoverflow just doesn't let you post two hyperlinks in a new post ;)

Next, check your files for `downloader/pearlib/pear.ini` - if it's got paths to the old location, typically you remove pear.ini and reinstall your extensions in the connect manager since their entries disappear (they're hooked to pear.ini, but removing the .ini does not remove the extensions - just their entries in the connect manager list).

After these changes have been made, go into your 'var' folder in your files and remove the 'cache' and 'session' folders. Re-login to your Magento admin and try it again.

Comment: I like your stipulation that Magento is a delicate piece of software:)